# How to serialize and deserialize objects that contains HashMaps and Pairs using GSON

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

I have this Hashmap `Map<Pair<String,String>,Map<String,String>> pathData = new HashMap<>();` as an attribute of other object (Tour_Object) and i'm trying to serialize/deserialize it in json using GSON library.

```
public static String setTourToJson(Tour_Object tourObject)
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(tourObject);
}

public static Tour_Object getTourFromJson(String JsonString)
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(JsonString, new TypeToken<Tour_Object>() {
    }.getType());
}
```

The following exception is thrown when I proceed to the deserialization:

```
04-19 11:18:49.449 29076-29076/abff.fxguide E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: abff.fxguide, PID: 29076
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 100 path $.pathData.
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:879)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:844)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:793)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:765)
at abff.fxguide.Tour_Helper.getTourFromJson(Tour_Helper.java:311)
at abff.fxguide.Tour_All.showTourDetails(Tour_All.java:266)
at abff.fxguide.Tour_All$8.onClick(Tour_All.java:370)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 100 path $.pathData.
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:388)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:183)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:186)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:216)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:879) 
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:844) 
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:793) 
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:765) 
at abff.fxguide.Tour_Helper.getTourFromJson(Tour_Helper.java:311) 
at abff.fxguide.Tour_All.showTourDetails(Tour_All.java:266) 
at abff.fxguide.Tour_All$8.onClick(Tour_All.java:370) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4856) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19956) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

I would like to know if the main object (Tour_Object) is deserializable as shown in `getTourFromJson(String JsonString)` when using attributes like pathData?

Comment: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/45

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR You need an adapter.

Gson can work with `Map` without an explicit adapter but it just expects the key to be a `String` because it translates the map to a JSON object. If it is not a `String` it converts it to one usually just calling `Object#toString()`.

Another way to put it is: how is the JSON representation of your object? Not obvious, because you can't have complex objects as properties on an JSON object, they are always strings.

So you need to decide your representation **and** write a custom adapter for it.

### Extended bonus anwser

As a bonus I can suggest you think in something like an array to represent your pathData. Instead of a map you write an array of objects which are key/value pairs. Something like this:

```
{
    "pathData": [
        {
            "pair": {"a": "one", "b": "two"},
            "map": { ... }
        },
        {
            "pair": {"a": "one", "b": "two"},
            "map": { ... }
        }
    ]
}
```

Where `pair`is your `Pair<String,String>` and `map` is your `Map<String,String>`.

Then you could write the `TypeAdapter` like this.

```
package net.sargue.gson;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SO36716159 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tour_Object o = new Tour_Object();
    o.pathData.put(new Pair<>("one", "two"), Collections.emptyMap());
    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("a", "b");
    myMap.put("c", "d");
    o.pathData.put(new Pair<>("three", "four"), myMap);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Tour_Object.class,
                                 new TourObjectAdapter())
            .setPrettyPrinting()
            .create();
    String json = gson.toJson(o);
    System.out.println("json = " + json);
  }

  public static class Pair<A, B> {
    private A a;
    private B b;

    public Pair(A a, B b) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
    }
  }

  public static class Tour_Object {
    private Map<Pair<String, String>, Map<String, String>> pathData = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<Pair<String, String>, Map<String, String>> pathData() {
      return pathData;
    }
  }

  public static class TourObjectAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Tour_Object> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Tour_Object value)
            throws IOException
    {
      Gson gson = new Gson();

      out.beginObject()
         .name("pathData")
         .beginArray();

      for (Map.Entry<Pair<String, String>, Map<String, String>> entry :
              value.pathData().entrySet()) {

        out.beginObject();
        out.name("pair");
        gson.getAdapter(new TypeToken<Pair<String,String>>() {})
            .write(out, entry.getKey());
        out.name("map");
        gson.getAdapter(new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {})
            .write(out, entry.getValue());
        out.endObject();
      }
      out.endArray()
         .endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Tour_Object read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
      throw new RuntimeException("Left as an exercise for the reader... ;-)");
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**: is not a complete example, only serialization and without too much checking and so. Valid only as an example.

The output of the previous code is:

```
json = {
  "pathData": [
    {
      "pair": {
        "a": "one",
        "b": "two"
      },
      "map": {}
    },
    {
      "pair": {
        "a": "three",
        "b": "four"
      },
      "map": {
        "a": "b",
        "c": "d"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```